# Search for a struct item in a vector by member data

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I'm very new to c++ and I'm trying to find a way to search a vector of structs for a struct with a certain member data.

I know this would work with simple types in the vector

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end()
```

But lets say I have a struct like this:

```
struct Friend
{
  string name;
  string number;
  string ID;
};
```

and a vector like this:

```
vector<Friend> friends;
```

Then the vector is filled with friends.

Let's say I want to search for a friend with a certain ID, and cout the details. Or delete the certain struct from the vector. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 29):

This can be done with [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and a search predicate, which can be expressed as a lambda function if you have C++11 (or C++0x) available:

```
auto pred = [](const Friend & item) {
    return item.ID == 42;
};
std::find_if(std::begin(friends), std::end(friends), pred) != std::end(friends);
```

To use an ID given as a variable, you have to *capture* it in the lambda expression (within the `[...]`):

```
auto pred = [id](const Friend & item) {
    return item.ID == id;
};
std::find_if(std::begin(friends), std::end(friends), pred) != std::end(friends);
```

If you don't have C++11 available, you have to define the predicate as a functor (function object). [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14226007/592323) uses this approach.

To remove elements matching the criteria as defined by the predicate, use `remove_if` instead of `find_if` (the rest of the syntax is the same).

For more algorithms, see [the STL `<algorithm>` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: It's a nice usage of auto!

Comment: @DanDan Yeah, sometimes I don't want to define the lambda directly where it is used as an argument to a function (it makes the line so long)

Comment: why does the first use `.begin()` and the second `std::begin`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks, it was a mistake. I changed it from the one to the other, so it is compatible with raw arrays.

Comment: @leemes This is my gripe with lambdas too, but I never thought of doing this.  It's a great idea!

Answer (score 15):

Use [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).  @leemes and @AndyProwl showed you how to use it in a C++11 compiler.  But if you are not using a C++11 compiler, then you can use it like this instead, which defines a functor comparing the ID of a given item with a previously specified ID in its constructor:

```
class MatchesID
{
    std::string _ID;

public:
    MatchesID(const std::string &ID) : _ID(ID) {}

    bool operator()(const Friend &item) const
    {
        return item.ID == _ID;
    }
};

std::find_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), MatchesID("TheIDHere")) != vector.end();
```

If you have other classes in your project which use IDs, you can make this functor templated:

```
template<typename IDType>
class MatchesID
{
    IDType _ID;

public:
    MatchesID(const IDType &ID) : _ID(ID) {}

    template<class ItemType>
    bool operator()(const ItemType &item) const
    {
        return item.ID == _ID;
    }
};

std::find_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), MatchesID<std::string>("TheIDHere")) != vector.end();
```

Comment: I made your functor generic, so it can be used with other types.

Comment: @leemes: If you go that approach then I would suggest using a template for the data type of the ID as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::find_if` in combination with functors (if you are working with C++98) or lambdas (if you are using C++11, which I will assume):

```
using namespace std;
int ID = 3; // Let's say...
auto it = find_if(begin(vector), end(vector), [=] (Friend const& f) { 
    return (f.ID == ID); 
    });
bool found = (it != end(vector));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find an element in STL container, use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithms
With C++03, you need to overload operator== for std::find

```
bool operator==(const Friend& lhs, const Friend& rhs)
{
  return lhs.ID == rhs.ID;
}

if (std::find(friends.begin(), friends.end(), item) != friends.end())
{
   // find your friend
}
```

OR C++11 with lambda:

```
std::find_if(friends.begin(), friends.end(),  [](Friend& f){ return f.ID == "1"; } );
```

If you want to remove a certain element, use [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

```
std::remove_if(friends.begin(), friends.end(), 
      [](Friend& f){ return f.ID == "1"; });
```

Comment: This way you don't keep the logic local. The definition of the equality of `Friend` instances can be different in some other scenario. Just saying... (It should be OK, since the ID should be unique anyway)

Comment: yeah, that's the beautify from C++11