# Using the find_if() function

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector of structs say "v". I need to find a certain item of "v" whose ID matches a given id.

I have found in another post that the way to go is "find_if". So I implemented the following:

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(id))!= v.end();
```

NB: I have correctly created MatchesID class, following the advice in the post.

Now, how can I access the particular vector item that contains the "id" I searched for?

I tried:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if (v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(id));
```

but it gives errors.

EDIT: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'

EDIT2: For completeness, I was also based on the post:  [Search for a struct item in a vector by member data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225932/search-for-a-struct-item-in-a-vector-by-member-data)

Comment: which errors does it give?

Comment: Have you tried `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`? Also, another alternative is just to use `auto` and have the compiler figure out the the type for you.

Comment: please show the definition of `MatchesID`

Comment: If it's a vector of structs, it seems like the iterator type should be vector<struct...>::iterator. Or you could just write "auto it = ..." if your compiler supports C++11

Comment: You should specify exactly what the type of `v` is. For maximal efficiency, you should actually supply a **complete** example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I would use a typedef for your vector of structs - 
e.g. typedef std::vector<MyType> MyTypeVector;  
Then you can use MyTypeVector::iterator.

Comment: nimrodm, many thanks - that was it!
Apologies for that stupid error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that your vector has `struct`s say of type `mystruct` (i.e., you have a `std::vector<mystruct>`). Yet, you are assigning an iterator `std::vector<mystruct>::iterator` that `std::find_if` will return to an iterator of type `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Solution:

```
std::vector<mystruct>::iterator it = std::find_if (v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(id));
```

or

```
auto it = std::find_if (v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is degraded to "how do I make this work"

`auto there= std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(id))!= v.end();`

And the answer is

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct MatchesID
{
    int id;
    MatchesID(int id): id(id){}
    bool operator()(int id){ return this-> id== id; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int>::iterator i= std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MatchesID(42));
}
```

You can compare it to your version to find the error.