# Search for a struct element in vector by id and return name

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct deviceDescription_t
{
    std::string deviceID;
    std::string deviceDescription;
};
```

I have defined a vector as follows:

```
std::vector<deviceDescription_t> deviceList
```

Let's say the vector `deviceList` is made up of the following elements:

```
ID    Description
=================
one_1  Device 1
two_2  Device 2
three_3 Device 3
....
```

I need to search through the ID field in `deviceList` and get the description for this. Let's say I have `one` as the predicate (search string). I now have to look through the ID field in the deviceList to find a match which I am doing by using

```
std::string temp = deviceID.substr(0, deviceID.find("_"));
```

but I am not sure how to use the `find_if` mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225932/search-for-a-struct-item-in-a-vector-by-member-data) question.

As one answer, it is advised to use

```
auto iter = std::find_if(deviceList.begin(), deviceList.end(),
            [&](deviceDescription_t const & item) {return item.deviceID == temp;});
```

Using the above in my function, throws the following error

> Local class, struct or union definitions are not allowed in a member function of a managed class.

Could anyone please guide me on how to use find_if to find the element matching the search criteria and return the description?

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. With the little you show it's impossible to say anything for certain.

Comment: Compiled OK In native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like you have a C++/CLI project.

When a lambda is used inline like you have in the call to `find_if()`, it is really creating a small class for you that overrides `operator ()`. Unfortunately the only way to call `find_if()` from a managed class is to do that yourself:

```
struct DeviceFinder
{
public:
    DeviceFinder(const std::wstring& temp)
    : m_temp(temp)
    {
    }

    bool operator() (const deviceDescription_t& item) const
    {
        return item.deviceID == m_temp;
    }

private:
    const std::wstring& m_temp;
};
```

And then you would call `find_if()` like this:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(deviceList.begin(), deviceList.end(),
                         DeviceFinder(temp));
```

Comment: In the comparison operator you can write any logic you want: 

bool operator() (const deviceDescription_t& item) 
{ 
   auto pos = item.deviceID.find("_"));
   if (pos == std::string::npos) return false;
   return  item.deviceID.substr(0, pos) == m_temp;
}

Comment: @Andy how should I go about assigning iter.deviceDescription to a string variable like say, `std::string temp = (*iter).description` throws an error.

Comment: Error: vector iterator not dereferencable

Comment: @smyslov are you sure that `find_if()` found an item in the vector? I can only recreate that if an item wasn't found. You can check if a device was found by comparing `iter` to `deviceList.end()`.