# Can I use std::find() with lambda function in vc++ [VS 2019]?

Tags: c++, c++11

- **OS**: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit(10.0, build 18362)
- **IDE**: Visual Studio 2019(Version 16.4.3) [***Before this I was using VS 2010***]
- **Language**: c++ and VC++

Here's my simple code in which i just want to find element 3 and print it if found

```
    std::vector<int> intVect;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
    {
        intVect.push_back(counter);
    }

    std::find(intVect.begin(), intVect.end(), [](int a)
        {
            if (a == 3)
            {
                std::cout << "Item Found.." << std::endl;
            }
        });
```

The probelm is when i compile this code it's giving me error like below:

> Error C2678   binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\algorithm 41

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily without a lambda:

```
auto val = std::find(intVect.begin(), intVect.end(), 3);
if (val != intVect.end()) {
   std::cout << "Value found\n";
}
```

However, it's also possible to use a lambda, but you need to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (available in the same header as `std::find`: `<algorithm>`):

```
auto val = std::find_if(intVect.begin(), intVect.end(), [](int i) { return i == 3; });
if (val != intVect.end()) {
   std::cout << "Value found\n";
}
```

But there's really no point. You'd only use `find_if` in this case if you had something more complex, like a `struct` and you were searching for a particular member:

```
struct complex {
   int id;
   ...
};
std::vector<complex> things = ...;
auto val = std::find_if(things.begin(), things.end(), [](const complex& c) { return c.id == 3; });
if (val != things.end()) {
    std::cout << "Value found\n";
}
```

Comment: yes  I have something more complex, like a struct and i were searching for a particular member and your suggetion working fine.. Thansk a lot Tas

Comment: @SKSingh had you just asked THAT question up front, then you would have been directed to existing duplicate questions, such as [Search for a struct item in a vector by member data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225932/).

Answer (score 3):

[`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) expects a value to be compared to elements, so it should be

```
if (std::find(intVect.begin(), intVect.end(), 3) != intVect.end())
{
    std::cout << "Item Found.." << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to use a lambda as predicate, you should use `std::find_if`; note that the lambda should return `bool`.

```
if (std::find_if(intVect.begin(), intVect.end(), [](int a) { return (a == 3); }) != intVect.end())
{
    std::cout << "Item Found.." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you comment. your suggetion is better as per my question but i were searching for more complex like class or struct. Its my silly mistake while asking question.